# Showing random objects in Django template

Tags: django, random, django-templates

In my Django template as I am iterating through a list of objects, I'd like to have one list item say:

```
<li><a href="{{ obj.green_link }}">Blah</a></li>
```

and then another do:

```
<li><a href="{{ obj.blue_link }}">Blah</a></li>
```

I see value|random as an option but for some reason this doesn't work:

```
{% ifequal [1, 2]|random 1 %}
    <a href="{{ post.adfly_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>

{% else %}
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>

{% endifequal %}
```

Doing this throws this error:

```
u'ifequal' takes two arguments
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I would think it should be simple but I realize the Django templating language doesn't allow for variable assignments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a list directly into the template like that, make_list is what you're after.

make_list returns a list of strings, so this would work.

```
{% if 12|make_list|random == '1' %}
   <li><a href="{{ obj.green_link }}">Blah</a></li>
{% else %}
   <li><a href="{{ obj.blue_link }}">Blah</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Given how ugly that piece of code is, what's the nicest way to turn that into a very quick class function instead?  And would it be shorter in the template?

Comment: I don't know, I reckon it could be uglier. But yes, sure you could - maybe write a method on your obj object:

def random_link(self):
    return random.choice((self.green_link, self.blue_link))